# Android Emulator sdcard not updating properly

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a simple Android app that pulls all music files on the phone and displays in a listView.  The code works fine, but any time I change a song on the sdcard, either adding or deleting, the changes are not displayed.  It looks as if the sdcard is cached or something.  If I remount the sdcard, the changes are displayed.  I can shut down the emulator and start it back up and still nothing changes until I remount.  How can I get the emulator to read changes on the sdcard without having to remount every time there is a change?  Am I missing a setting or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add any media file to emulator you have to run Menu-->Dev Tools-->Media Scanner

to make it visible in gallery or any other application in emulator.

Comment: can this be done in code? Like on my onResume function to capture any changes that may have taken place? Also, if you save something to sdcard, nothing can find it until the media scanner has taken place?