# While creating sub directory in sd card on emulator getting permissions denied error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-sdcard

i am trying to create sd card on emulator.
in devtools in terminal emulator i gave cmds $cd sdcard
$mkdir pictures but is showing error mkdir failed for pictures,permissions denied.
please help me how to create sdcard on emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Eclipce then follow these steps

goto Window->AVD manager->select the AVD for which you want to create the sdcard then click edit on sd card panel give the size->edit AVD

to show the image after upload u have to run

Menu-->Dev Tools-->Media Scanner

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130328/android-emulator-sdcard-not-updating-properly/9130491#9130491)

is't this simple?

Comment: i created in avd but i want to copy images in gallery.In image upload i want to upload images but in gallery of emulator there no images how to copy images into gallery

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the permission in manifest before you do so.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-      
permission>
```

Include this to create a directory.

```
String extStorageDirectory = "/mnt/sdcard/Foldername/";
File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory); 
if ( !myNewFolder.exists() ) 
   myNewFolder.mkdir();
```

Comment: i m not giving this in program i m giving in emulator then how can i add permissions in android manifest file

Comment: To create a folder in sd card start an emulator and include sdcard in the available options, after this in your application there will be a manifest file in that you can give the permission.

Comment: thanks now i am able to create folder pictures in the sdcard but i m trying to copy images in that pictures folder.                            String extStorageDirectory = "/mnt/sdcard/pictures/"; 
        File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory); 
        myNewFolder.mkdir();                                          FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myNewFolder); 
        Bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80, myNewFolder); 
        myNewFolder.flush(); myNewFolder.close();       but it is showing error at flush,close.please help me how to copy images to that pictures folder

Answer (score 0):

This method can be used to copy a file from source to destination.
    public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst);

```
    // Transfer bytes from in to out
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
        out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All issues with permission come from using the default sdcard image. So simply create a new sdcard image.

To do this, open AVD Manager in Android Studio, click on "Show Advanced Settings" on the bottom of the screen and then create a new sdcard image. Both options are marked on the image below.

[image]

After this you will be able to use console to create images, push files, and other tasks.